# Settings icon on uinavigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to figure out a way to set the left corner nav button to be a settings gear on a view controller that is embedded in a navigation controller.  I read that it might be accomplished with a Unicode sequence..does anyone know how?  or would I just be better using an icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find an image for your settings icon make it 40x40px (and 80x80 for retina @2x) and put a barbutton item:

```
UIBarButtonItem *leftBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(yourSettingsMethod)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBtn;
```